# MVVMCROSS Fragment sample not working with rotation

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mvvmcross

I just started out with learning how to use MVVMCross with Android using Xamarin Studio. I am fairly new to Android development.

I am porting an iOS app to Android and when I rotate my screen my app crashes when using fragments. I thought the problem was just me doing something wrong but when I run the sample project attached to the sample video the same thing happens. The error i get is " No default constructor found".

The Sample app I used at github : https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments

Can someone please help me out to why this is happening ?

Comment: I just tried both https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-26-Fraggle and https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Fragments with the latest 3.0.14-beta2 binaries. I tried the forms, the tabs, the split screens and didn't see the error. Could you perhaps edit the question to provide more detailed information about how/when you see the error, what you are testing on, and what the full error message and stack trace is. We can try to help - but please help us by providing as good a question as possible. Thanks

Comment: A new example that handles this is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: links are broken!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging, I "think" you are asking about how to handle rotation for a `DialogFragment` - I hope I've got that right.

If you do want to handle rotation in Android, then you have to:

- provide the default constructor and you have to make use of the fragment tag
- provide some code in the `Activity.OnCreate` handler in order to ensure that the `DialogFragment` has its `ViewModel` set after the rotation occurs.

I've just done this for the sample you mention in this commit - https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/commit/ebe1777ec79ee2607b1b863f6b8b3911c12df53f

---

Note that to really fully support the Activity lifecycle - e.g. including loading/saving state when the App or Activity is "tombstoned" - then you should also go further than this - should save/restore all View and ViewModel state. MvvmCross does contain some helpers for this in the `SaveState` and `ReloadState` ViewModel methods - but even with these then fully supporting the Activity lifecycle can be quite a pain (which is why some apps don't fully support it, but instead show a "new" display instead)

Comment: I thought so thank you so much stuart :) keep up the good work!